# Hash length extension attack - SHA256 to 512 - impossible, correct?

Tags: hash, sha-256, sha-512, length-extension

Just want to be sure about something before I sign off on a method we're about to put into place.

We have a secret, to which a user-defined key is appended. The user can see the SHA256 hash of the secret.

The secret and the user-key is then hashed with SHA512 to obtain results.

Given the ending hash is SHA512, and the user only knows the SHA256, a hash length extension attack would be impossible, correct? As there is no way to convert a 256 to 512, or to backtrack the 256?

From every angle I can see it, it shouldn't be possible. But want to confirm with those more well versed than I. Thanks.

Comment: Of course, it would probably be better is the user can see a [commitment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commitment_scheme) to the secret instead of the SHA256 hash of the secret, and if the user-key is then [HMAC](http://eprint.iacr.org/2014/578.pdf)ed with the secret instead of them being hashed with SHA512. $\;$

Comment: Guys, maybe something for meta, but I see very few people upvoting questions. Now I can understand not upvoting questions if they are too specific but there seems to be a growing gap between the amount of upvotes for answers and questions.

Comment: Even if there's no known way I would recommend creating a canonical representation of messages, e.g. by prefixing the length for the user-key. Somebody may look at your code and decide that using a single hash function would be more efficient. At the very minimum create a design document and comment your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no known way.

It would actually be rather surprising if there were even a theoretical way; the SHA-256 and the SHA-512 compression functions are rather different (for one, one works with 32 bit words and the other works with 64 bit words); one wouldn't expect them to share any sort of relation.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, would the different initial values be enough to thwart a length extension attack?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes: yes; different initial values would.  In fact, that's precisely the reason why (for example) SHA-256 and SHA-224 use different initial values.